# Workaround to set an http proxy on a Samsung Smart TV?

Tags: wireless-networking, mac, proxy, tv, proxy-server

I would to set a foreigner http proxy on my Samsung smart tv in order to use some applications available to use just on that country.
Samsung does not let change the the proxy server via configuration, so I tried to share the ethernet connection on my Mac (where I changed the http web proxy) via WIFI. Whereas on my Mac I can surf the web as I would be with on the foreigner country the TV connected to the shared connection still thinks to be on the current country. Why? Do you think of any workaround?
Thanks

Comment: Unless doing transparent proxying (via packet mangling), the settings on your Mac only affect programs that actively look for that setting. Since your TV isn’t a program on your Mac, it can’t possibly be affected by that setting.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, do you believe there is a workaround to let the TV have a foreigner IP address?

Comment: As Daniel said, you need to set up a transparent proxy. A quick Google search should tell you how to set it up.

Comment: Indeed. Alternatively, a full-blown VPN is also a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I used a (paid) VPN service for this reason the other day. I had a USA Samsung smart tv, but I'm living in Japan. The TV set wouldn't work connecting to Samsung servers for the initial user agreement confirmation screen (something like that), no matter how I tried the connection would fail.
So I set up a VPN connection on my MacBook Pro and also shared Wi-Fi from the MacBook. Then connected the Samsung tv to that Wi-Fi and voila.

The VPN service I used is expressvpn but it would likely work with just about any VPN service. Expressvpn has a nice documentation  for this exact purpose so it was easy to set up however.

Btw the tv wouldn't fail out later for not using the VPN. I think Samsung only silently does a geoip check in that first on boarding process, before you're allowed to access their App Store.